# OSX10.11.3 How to combine disk partitions?

Tags: macos, disk-utility

I installed two OS’s on my MacBook Air — macOS and Windows — thus it has two disk partitions: Machintosh HD (40G) and BOOTCAMP (80G).

I have decided to remove Windows from my MacBook. I used to the Disk Utility tool erased BOOTCAMP partition, but when I tried to use "Partition" menu to merge BOOTCAMP partition into Machintosh HD, Machintosh HD's size couldn't adjusted.

I just realized that I should have used the Boot Camp Assistant to remove BOOTCAMP partition, but since I have erased BOOTCAMP partition, this way no longer works.

Given my current situation, how can be remove BOOTCAMP, and merge all disk space back to Machintosh HD?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actively resize the boot partition for OS X and a few other operating systems. What you can do start up your Mac in Recovery mode.

To do this, power down and Press and hold one of the key sequences below immediately after you turn on your Mac and hear the startup sound.

- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> - to start up from OS X Recovery if you have a recovery partition
- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>  - to Start up from OS X Recovery over the Internet.
- <kbd>C</kbd> - to start up from a bootable CD, DVD, or USB thumb drive (such as OS X install media).

Once you're in OS Setup, you can choose Disk Manager from the Tools menu and resize your Macintosh HD partition.

Answer (score -2):

Open Disk Utility ( you may do it from Spotlight) , click on the main drive ( Apple SSD Media in my case) , select partition from the options , click on bootcamp and then click '-' (subtract) sign.